# forever a py script writing a value to a file (fobj) doesn't update the file

Tags: python, forever

I've a python script which reads a sensor and writes it's value in loop in a file in the same folder the script is located. That part is working fine when I run the script in command line.

Now I wanted to keep that script running in background. So I used forever for that. That seems to work too as I'm not getting any errors.

But the problem I'm facing, the forever script does not update the value in the file. I've searched for that file on the whole system, thinking maybe forever runs the script from another place but I can't find a copy of that file.

I guess it's just a small hint why I don't get an updated file but I can't find the reason for that.

I work with fobj in the py scrip.

Comment: Definitely need to see some code. But some wild guesses .. give the absolute path of the file.. log some data to std out or err and see where is it writing or doing something

Comment: Good guess. I've done what you said and the problem is, that if I run the python script with forever it doesn't execute it in the project folder so I get errors in the log pointing to missing modules or missing files regarding to their path.

is there a way to run the py with forever out of its origin?

Comment: can you put here the exact command that you are using to run

Answer (score 0):

Run it like this

```
forever --sourceDir /path/to/yourscript yourscript  
#your current working directory will become /path/to/yourscript
```